# Issuing Linq queries against a DB using EF

Tags: entity-framework

I am looking for a way to let my users run linq queries against a database.

For example, the user might type "from p in product select p.Name" and then get the results in the UI.

Ideally, it would use the Entity Framework to do its job.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to code your own parser and build expression trees or compile queries at runtime then probably no. But you can check [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx) - it is like SQL run on Entity model.

Or you can install LinqPad to your users - but that is really corner solution.